# how to write query to change the delimter in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY hdfs://gitlabhadoopnn.cs.aibl:8020/ABDF/anus/testdir'  
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '9' 
SELECT * from TEST;
```

But execution fails with following error:

```
cannot recognize input near 'ROW' 'FORMAT' 'DELIMITED' in statement
```

Please suggest a method to execute insert query with delimiter specification option.

Comment: missing a quote near `hdfs` or a typo ?

Comment: `'hdfs://gitlabhadoopnn.cs.aibl:8020/ABDF/anus/testdir'  `

Answer (score 1):

What is your version of Hive?
You should check this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries).

> As of Hive 0.11.0 the separator used can be specified; in earlier versions it was always the ^A character (\001). However, custom separators are only supported for LOCAL writes in Hive versions 0.11.0 to 1.1.0 – this bug is fixed in version 1.2.0 (see HIVE-5672).

Check [HIVE-5672](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5672) and Hive version.

You can try to do this and check if it works:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/tmp/test'  
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '9' 
SELECT * from TEST;
```

Comment: thanks , you are right ,I changed to hive 1.2.0 its working